# Marshmallow Str() does not work but Function() does

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am trying out `marshmallow` for serializing my data objects, because even though just writing out json dicts is really damn easy, for some reason everyone thinks it's more pythonic to use a package.

Problem is, it doesn't work the way it's advertised.  The `Str()` field is supposed to make a string from an attribute of the same name; the `Function()` field is required to perform code execution.  I don't think code execution should be required here, but `Str()` is not working but `Function()` is.

```
>>> q.origin
'local.qdb'

>>> from marshmallow import Schema, fields
>>> class StrSchema(Schema):
        origin = fields.Str()

>>> StrSchema().dump(q)
MarshalResult(data={'origin': ''}, errors={})

>>> class FunctionSchema(Schema):
        origin = fields.Function(lambda x: x.origin)

>>> FunctionSchema().dump(q)
MarshalResult(data={'origin': 'local.qdb'}, errors={})
```

Am I missing something?  `q` here is a complicated object, but it has an `_origin` attribute and an `origin` property that just returns the attribute.  When I just create a dummy object that has those characteristics, it does not demonstrate the problem. There is no trickery in the `origin` property of `q` so I don't know what's wrong.  But I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: it is in the `utils` file, in the function `_get_value_for_key`:

```
def _get_value_for_key(key, obj, default):
    try:
        return obj[key]
    except (KeyError, AttributeError, IndexError, TypeError):
        try:
            attr = getattr(obj, key)
            return attr() if callable(attr) else attr
        except AttributeError:
            return default
    return default
```

Basically, Marshmallow tries to `__getitem__` before it tries `getattr`; my object was returning empty on `__getitem__` rather than raising a key error.

This is probably a documentation error.

Comment: With some distance, I can see it was a rather unforgivable error on my part to allow __getitem__ to return None rather than raising a KeyError